# Problem with the background image?

Tags: graphics, backgrounds

I am trying to insert a background image in my LaTeX file, but as I write the commands and compile, the background images are in the correct positions but the rest of the images get shifted to the end of the document.

I am using `\begin{figure}[h].....\end{figure}`. Still the images get displaced whereas when I run the same file without background image, the rest of the images come to their proper places.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `wallpaper` package can help you with background images.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make a poster (or presentation), or any ordinary writing doc? I have done a poster where I put a \usebackgroundtemplate in Beamer. In that case my attempt was successful.[image]. If you are trying to do this type, I can send you my script...or in a short form it is --

```
\documentclass[final, 12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=77,height=107,scale=1.4,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig,xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx,amsthm,multirow,amsmath}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}% text under figure
\usepackage{fancybox}%different shape box
\usepackage{mdframed}%framed
\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\centering \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=120cm]{AGC_figure/P-1.jpg}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.85}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}

\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\setbeamercolor{uppercolgreen}{fg=white,bg=green!35}%Using this you can change the box color
\setbeamercolor{lowercolgreen}{fg=black,bg=green!10}
\setbeamercolor{eecks} {bg=white, fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{eecks2}{bg=white, fg=blue}



\setbeamercovered{transparent=80!}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\pgfsetfillopacity{0.85}


\begin{textblock}{}(0.2,1.1)%
\begin{varblock}[35cm]{\textbf{1. Introduction}}


\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{6.8cm}

\centering
\vspace{-2cm}
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{AGC_figure/P-2.pdf} 
\end{wrapfigure}


\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}


\begin{textblock}{}(0.2,3.55)%
\begin{varblock}[34cm]{\textbf{3. Site \& Equipment}}


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------your text-------------------------------------

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{l}{10.5cm}
\vspace{-1cm}
\centering
\hspace{-1cm}
\includegraphics[height=7.5cm]{AGC_figure/P-3.pdf} 
\end{wrapfigure}
{conditions.}
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```